# ValueError: view limit minimum -36834.700000?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting the maximum and minimum temperatures from a data file, for the years 1998 and 2017. The 2017 section was missing some days so it only had 345 days, and 1998 had 365 days. Here is what I have:

```
napa=pd.read_csv('MET 51 Final data selection.csv')

maxtemp=napa['TMAX']
mintemp=napa['TMIN']
days=[i for i in range(365)]
days2=[i for i in range(345)]
plot(days,maxtemp[7273:7638],'r--',label='Maximum Temperatures (1998)')
plot(days,mintemp[7273:7638],'b--',label='Minimum Temperatures (1998)')
plot(days2,maxtemp[14172:14517],color='crimson',label='Maximum Temperatures (2017)')
plot(days2,mintemp[14172:14517],color='deepskyblue',label='Minimum Temperatures (2017)')
xlabel('Time (Days)')
ylabel('Temperature (F)')
title('Napa State Hospital Maximum & Minimum Temperatures 1998 VS 2017')
legend()
show()
```

However, I keep getting the error that says this:

```
ValueError: view limit minimum -36834.700000000004 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong?